# Is there a way to use get row sums with specified variables

Tags: r, dplyr, rowsum

I would like to get the sum rows but excluding a given row. Listing all the variables is a bit tedious. I would like to highlight by position the variable to exclude in the operation. Any idea?

```
library(tidyverse)


df <- tribble(
  ~"var1", ~"var2", ~"var3", ~"var4",
  "A", 20, 10, 23, 
  "B", 30, 6, 34, 
  "C", 40, 8, 23, 
  "D", 50, 10, 24
  
)

# This is the desired output 
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(var2, var3, var4))
```

Comment: What condition(s) to exclude or include rows?

Comment: To exclude variable var1

Comment: `var1` is a column. What's not working with your desired output?

Comment: Oooh sorry for not being very clear. My desire is to get the row sums of all the columns except the first column.

Comment: You could use base R: `df$total <- rowSums(df[, 2:4])`

Comment: However I would not want to list all the columns to include in the operation

Comment: You can also use across: `sum(across(-var1)))`

Comment: df$total <- rowSums(df[, 2:4]) answers the question. Would you @Peter kindly post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use base R:

```r
df$total <- rowSums(df[, 2:4])

df

#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   var1   var2  var3  var4 total
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A        20    10    23    53
#> 2 B        30     6    34    70
#> 3 C        40     8    23    71
#> 4 D        50    10    24    84
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dplyr` solution that uses `select`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(total = rowSums(select(., -var1)))
```

```
  var1   var2  var3  var4 total
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        20    10    23    53
2 B        30     6    34    70
3 C        40     8    23    71
4 D        50    10    24    84
```